# How to write Junit testcases for hive JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, junit, hive, in-memory-database

How to write JUnit test cases for Hive jdbc. In hive I don't think for the same code we can use in memory db. Without in memory db test cases may be the test cases will be fail. 
Can I used embedded Hive to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could test the hive code using

https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/hive_test

or

https://github.com/klarna/HiveRunner

I but I am not sure that either has jdbc support, but you really need to test the jdbc call you could just mock out the database.